# Collaborative tree/hierarchical note taking software

Tags: note-taking, collaboration, collection-manager, multi-user

Requirements:

- Hierarchical/tree based structuring of notes
- Multi user (simultaneous access to *different* notes)
- Definitely *NOT* SaaS
- Not an Emacs/Vim plugin

Want (but not need):

- a GUI tool
- Libre/Open source

Don't care:

- if self-hosted web app or native program

Comment: Would you also like to use complex formatting, LaTeX, tables, embedded images in your notes?

Comment: It'd be a nice extra, but not something I (still) am looking for. (Sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 1):

How about Emacs's [Org mode](http://orgmode.org)?

- Hierarchical/tree based structuring of notes — Check. This is its most characteristic feature, as a descendant of outline.el.
- Multi user (simultaneous access to *different* notes) — This isn't provided by Org itself, but because Org documents are plain text, you can use generic tools such as SSH or version control systems (e.g., Git).
- Definitely *NOT* SaaS — Check.
- Libre/Open source — Check; it's part of a GNU product.

Org is a native application. It's written in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: Well, it doesn't sync automatically, which I would really, REALLY appreciate. And since I don't know how to work Emacs in the first place... Also, this answer is off-topic according to the help page. Which states "ready-to-use". Using multiple programs to accomplish this task is not what I would call "ready to use"

Comment: @Xunie Try [Tramp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode). Then, whenever you save the file, it's actually saved remotely. Same for loading.

Comment: @Xunie "Using multiple programs to accomplish this task is not what I would call 'ready to use'" — Welcome to the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

Comment: I can't expect these people to all grok Emacs, neither am I interested in learning **yet another** text editor just to take some notes. UNIX philosophy or not, still off-topic. ;-)